# Not able to edit pages in Aptana-Studio

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, aptana, eclipse-kepler

I have eclipse kepler installed as well as apatna studio, While eclipse is working fine, whenever i try to edit any page on aptana, i am getting this error :

```
 An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
 org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.getScrollbarsMode()I
```

`.log` from the `.metadata` file says (*showing only 1st 4 lines*):

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor 4 2 2014-07-31 22:44:29.901
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.getScrollbarsMode()I
```

I have searched all possible google links for this error, can any one please help me resolve the issue or point on right direction?

** *feel free to retag*

Comment: I loved your profile description. Totally made my day!

Comment: thanks fella...for whats its worth, we both made each others day!! :)

Comment: You have delivered on your promise of being chatty too. :P

Comment: @CodeNewbie : haha, that's because i am a person of my words!! ;) :p